# Mapping surrogate keys in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

How to map a surrogate key(which is a foreign key to other dimension table) in `ssis`.

I have `Dim.Camp` table like this :

```
Dim.Camp(campkey int identity(1,1),Advkey int,campbk int,campname varchar(10))

Dim.Adv(Advkey int identity(1,1),Advbk int)
```

The above are my dimension tables,

These are my staging tables:

```
Camp(Advid int,campid int,campname varchar(10))

Adv(Advid int)
```

I load my `Dim.camp` through loop up task in `ssis` using my staging tables :

Then i get:

```
Dim.Camp(campkey int identity(1,1),Advkey int,campbk int,campname varchar(10)) populated accept
```

`Advkey` which gets all Nulls in its column because there is no corresponding mapping in staging tables

Can somebody tell me what is it I'm doing wrong, ...or how to get this done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to know what is the relationship between the entities or tables "Camp" and "Adv" in your source system or in the staging table. You always need the business key to perform a lookup in the dimension tables, that is, you need the campbk to lookup records in the Dim.Camp and the Advbk to lookup records in the Dime.Camp dimension

If I understood correctly you should load first the Dim.Adv from staging using for instance a merge command in an execute SQL task or in a data flow task. Then you can load the Dim.Camp from Stage, something like this:

Source query:

`select Advid as Advbk,campid campbk,campname from Staging.Camp`

Then make a lookup (lookup table: Dim.Adv) and get the Dim.Advid where Dim.Adv.Advbk = Advbk

Finally make another lookup (table: Dim.Camp) and then determine if you have to update or insert the records.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Kind Regards,

Paul

Comment: can i use one table from staging and one table from DW ...like can i use Staging.Camp  lookup Dim.Adv ?? ...can you please link me to anysuch examples ? i think you got my problem thers no corresponding advkey to map ! in my staging.Adv !

Comment: You asked relationship btw the tables... Camp has Advid which is foreign key to Adv

Comment: You can use the staging.Camp.Advid to lookup the dim.Adv.Advid in the dim.Adv Table, then another lookup with the staging.Camp.campId to get the dim.Camp.Campid and then determine if you should insert or delete the incoming records

Comment: thanks a..lot and in my dim tables it has created_by,updated_by ... i am able to get created_by...but whenevr thers a change/update in records the corresponding updated_by should get populated..can you tell me how get that one...i used Slowly chaning dimension wizard in my ssis... but i dont get how to make updated_by !

Comment: Hi, could you please provide us the Change Type that your are using for the SCD.

Comment: sir, i'm using Type 2 change : when there is any update in any name(for ex) then corresponding updated_date is written and updated_by  is what i'm not getting ? ..can you also guide me when should type 1 or type 2 should be choosen ?

Comment: Hi @user3432208 The type of the SCD depends on what you want to do. If you want to keep the history of the changes for every record you need a type 2. If you want to overwrite the changes use a type 1. You can find a lot of learning material in the web, I recommend you the following article: [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/MERGE/73805/) How are you implementing the update_by and update_date?